# Will not let me click in text box when trying to mount my encrypted hard drive

Tags: mac, mojave

Will not let me type in the box when prompted for password when trying to unlock and mount my “Macintosh HD” became encrypted after upgrading too mojave.
Have tried things in terminal but no luck as of yet.
And worst of all no backups

Comment: Can you add informations on the material configuration? Have you try Reset SMC and Reset NVRAM?